# Flask app with "submodules"

Tags: python, flask, package

I am trying to develop an API with different "submodules". For example there is one called todo and another one called newsletter.

What I want to do is, I'd like to be able to run the modules themselves during development and I'd like to be able to run the whole API with it's submodules on the server.

My current folder structure looks like that

```
api
  - api
    - todo
      - todo
        - __init__.py
        - routes.py
        - utils.py
        - ...
      - README.md
      - requirements.txt
    - newsletter
      - ...
  - run.py
```

---

The aim is to be able to run this during development:

```
cd api/todo/todo
python3 run.py
```

And this on the server

```
python3 run.py
```

---

The routes should be relative:

During the production the path for one submodule should be like that

```
/add
```

But on the server they should always include the name of submodule

```
/todo/add
```

---

Moreover I'd like to be able to put the code of every submodule in one GitHub repository, so that other persons will be able to run them on themselves.

I am currently stuck on importing the modules. Can I fix the path *problem* by using Flasks Blueprints?

I would appreciate any help very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following project structure:

```
app
    api
        -todo
            -__init__.py
            -other_apis.py
        -newsletter
            -__init__.py
            -other_apis.py
    __init__.py
```

In the `app.api.todo.__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

todo = Blueprint("todo", __name__)
```

In the `app.api.newsletter.__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

newsletter = Blueprint("newsletter", __name__)
```

In the `app.__init__.py`:

```
from flask import FLask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app.api.todo import todo
from app.api.newsletter import newsletter

app.register_blueprint(todo, url_prefix="/api/todo")
app.register_blueprint(newsletter, url_prefix="/api/newsletter")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run()
```

And you can change which blueprint is registered and what url prefix bound to blueprint with environment variable.